# Is there a relation between autocorrelation and probability?How to know $E[X^2(t+1)]$ when knowing $E[X^2]$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, correlation, error-function

$X(t)$ is a Gaussian WSS process with $E${$X(t)$}$=0$ and $R(\tau)=2e^{-2|\tau|}$

1.Find the $P${$X(t) \le 3$},and just express it as Q-function

About the first question,according to $X(t)$ is WSS , i only know it can be fouriered to know its power , but i don't know how to calculate its probability when i know its autocorrelation , is there a relation between autocorrelation and probability ?

2.Determine $E${$(X(t+1)-X(t-1))^2$}

About the second question,when i express this formula,
\begin{align}
E[(X(t+1)-X(t-1))^2]
& = E[X^2(t+1)+X^2(t-1)-2X(t+1)X(t-1)] \\
& = E[X^2(t+1)]+E[X^2(t-1)]-E[2X(t+1)X(t-1)]
\end{align}

I think i can regard $E[2X(t+1)X(t-1)]$ as $2$ times of its autocorrelation when $\tau = 2$ , but i don't know how to solve $E[X^2(t+1)]$ and $E[X^2(t-1)]$ . It seems that i can use the variance , $\sigma ^2 = E[X^2(t)]-E^2[X(t)]$ , to know what is $E[X^2(t)]$ , but i don't know wheather i can also know $E[X^2(t+1)]$ and $E[X^2(t-1)]$ or not when i know $E[X^2]$ first

Comment: For the first: If I tell you that $X$ is gaussian with mean and variance $(0,\sigma^2)$ do you know how to compute $P(X\le 3)$? If so, then recall (or learn) that $R(0)=Var(X(t))$

Comment: The same goes for the second. I find strange that you understand that $E[X(t+1)X(t-1)]=R(2)$ but you don't seem to get that $E[X(t+1)X(t+1)]=E[X(t)X(t)]=R(0)$ ...

Comment: @leonbloy i don't know ,can you explain it a little more?

Comment: You are supposed to study stochastic process only after you have studied basic probability, just as you study matrix multiplication after you know how to multiply numbers. See eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function

Comment: but the website you provide should for the random variable,i know that.besides,in that website,it give me pdf first,so of course i know how to calculate the probabiltiy,and there is no some relation information between autocorrelation and probability.